# CakePHP 5.x: BelongsToMany association using the ‘through’ option

Tags: php, cakephp

in my app I have `users` and `notifications` tables.

I then added the `users_notifications` table with the `id`, `notification_id`, `user_id`, `is_read` and `reading_datetime` fields.

`is_read` (a boolean) and `reading_datetime` (a `DateTime` instance) are extra fields.

I then created a `BelongsToMany` association and I realized that **I have to use the option precisely because of those two extra fields**.

```php
class NotificationsTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        // ...

        $this->belongsToMany('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'notification_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'user_id',
            'through' => 'UsersNotifications',
        ]);
    }
}
```

```php
class UsersNotificationsTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        // ...

        $this->belongsTo('Notifications', [
            'foreignKey' => 'notification_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
    }
}
```

All of this seems to be working correctly so far.
Especially regarding the insertion of a notification (and users related to it), I have no problems.

Instead I have problems **recovering the data, paying particular attention to those two extra fields**.

Here, for example, let's say I want to retrieve the notifications for user #1, including the extra `is_read` and `reading_time` fields.

```php
$Query = $this->Notifications->find()
    ->matching('Users', fn(SelectQuery $Query): SelectQuery => $Query
        ->select(['id'])
        ->where(['Users.id' => 1]))
    ->all();
```

The result I get is this (I only report the first record):

```php
ROOT/templates/Notifications/index.php (line 20)
object(App\Model\Entity\Notification) id:0 {
  'id' => (int) 137
  'title' => 'Notizie anamnestiche'
  'text' => 'Una Nota "Notizie anamnestiche" è stata inserita da Ficca Erika con alta priorità'
  'priority' => 'high'
  'url' => [
    'controller' => 'Notes',
    'action' => 'view',
    (int) 0 => (int) 783,
  ]
  'created' => object(Cake\I18n\DateTime) id:1 {
    'hasFixedNow' => false
    'time' => '2024-01-02 18:12:13.000000'
    'timezone' => 'Europe/Rome'
  }
  '_matchingData' => [
    'Users' => object(App\Model\Entity\User) id:2 {
      'id' => (int) 1
      'full_name' => ''
      '[new]' => false
      '[accessible]' => [
        'users_group_id' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'password_expiration' => true,
        'first_name' => true,
        'last_name' => true,
        'mobile_phone' => true,
        'active' => true,
        'external_connection' => true,
        'created' => false,
        'modified' => false,
        'users_group' => false,
        'activities' => false,
        'activities_reports' => false,
        'notices' => false,
        'notes' => false,
        'notifications' => false,
        'nursing_registers' => false,
        'users_logins' => false,
      ]
      '[dirty]' => [
      ]
      '[original]' => [
      ]
      '[originalFields]' => [
        (int) 0 => 'id',
      ]
      '[virtual]' => [
        (int) 0 => 'full_name',
      ]
      '[hasErrors]' => false
      '[errors]' => [
      ]
      '[invalid]' => [
      ]
      '[repository]' => 'Users'
    },
    'UsersNotifications' => object(App\Model\Entity\UsersNotification) id:3 {
      'id' => (int) 137
      'notification_id' => (int) 137
      'user_id' => (int) 1
      'is_read' => true
      'reading_datetime' => object(Cake\I18n\DateTime) id:4 {
        'hasFixedNow' => false
        'time' => '2024-01-03 16:12:18.000000'
        'timezone' => 'Europe/Rome'
      }
      '[new]' => false
      '[accessible]' => [
        'notification_id' => true,
        'user_id' => true,
        'is_read' => true,
        'reading_datetime' => true,
        'notification' => true,
        'user' => true,
      ]
      '[dirty]' => [
      ]
      '[original]' => [
      ]
      '[originalFields]' => [
        (int) 0 => 'id',
        (int) 1 => 'notification_id',
        (int) 2 => 'user_id',
        (int) 3 => 'is_read',
        (int) 4 => 'reading_datetime',
      ]
      '[virtual]' => [
      ]
      '[hasErrors]' => false
      '[errors]' => [
      ]
      '[invalid]' => [
      ]
      '[repository]' => 'UsersNotifications'
    },
  ]
  '[new]' => false
  '[accessible]' => [
    'title' => true,
    'text' => true,
    'priority' => true,
    'url' => true,
    'created' => false,
    'users' => true,
  ]
  '[dirty]' => [
  ]
  '[original]' => [
  ]
  '[originalFields]' => [
    (int) 0 => 'id',
    (int) 1 => 'title',
    (int) 2 => 'text',
    (int) 3 => 'priority',
    (int) 4 => 'url',
    (int) 5 => 'created',
    (int) 6 => '_matchingData',
  ]
  '[virtual]' => [
  ]
  '[hasErrors]' => false
  '[errors]' => [
  ]
  '[invalid]' => [
  ]
  '[repository]' => 'Notifications'
}
```

The question, precisely, is: how to correctly access the `is_read` and `reading_time` fields? In the entity they are found in the `_matchingData` property (as the `UsersNotifications` entity, along with the `Users` entity which is ok there).

I didn't find anything more precise in the CookBook.

Maybe I should act directly on the `UsersNotifications` table and, in these cases, find the notifications starting from that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view try:

```
foreach ($query as $notification) {
    // Accessing the UsersNotifications entity
    $usersNotification = $notification->_matchingData['UsersNotifications'];

    // Accessing the is_read and reading_datetime fields
    $isRead = $usersNotification->is_read;
    $readingDateTime = $usersNotification->reading_datetime;

    // ... rest of your code ...
}
```

or DRY, in Notification Entity

```
public function getNotificationExtraData()
{
    return $this->_matchingData['UsersNotifications'];

}
```

in view:

```
foreach ($query as $notification) {
    $notification->getNotificationExtraData()->is_read;
}
```

Ensure that there are no errors, if the matching data is empty.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way except by accessing the `_matchingData` property. However, it is strange that the CookBook does not report this information. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong at the query level instead. You will therefore need to implement a method or use a virtual field. Thanks in the meantime.

Comment: The last paragraph of the [section about matching](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data) says "The data from the association that is ‘matched’ will be available on the _matchingData property of entities."